# Issues installing R package, r-base; Ubuntu 14

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I am having a massive headache trying to install R. I go to install r-base and I get the following.

```
root@10:/etc/apt > apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.2.4-revised-1trusty0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.2.4-revised-1trusty0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I go to install r-base-core and get this.

```
root@10:/etc/apt > apt-get install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libblas3 but it is not installable or
                        libblas.so.3 but it is not installable
               Depends: liblapack3 but it is not installable or
                        liblapack.so.3 but it is not installable
               Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libtcl8.6 (>= 8.6.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
               Depends: libtk8.6 (>= 8.6.0) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried this using the cran mirrors, using force, using aptitude. I cannot get this to install. Anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update`? What are your apt sources?

Comment: Yes I ran apt-get update. I got the sources directly from the guide on downloading R using the cran mirrors.

Comment: I think I have the same issue: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25443/install-r-3-6-3-on-elementary-os-unmet-dependencies Did you ever iron this out?